# Probability of rolling consecutive ones

Tags: probability

Here's the situation: I have a (fair) die, which I roll successively until I get 5 consecutive ones, in which case I stop rolling. My questions are:

1. What is the probability that I stop after exactly 11 throws? (or $k$ throws in general?)
2. What is the probability that I roll the die at least 9 times? (or $k$ times in general?)
3. More generally, is there a name for the kind of probability distribution involved?

For the first question, I'm thinking of the following string: $$ABCDEZ11111$$ where $ABCDE$ can be anything other than $11111$, and $Z$ can be anything other than $1$. The probability is therefore $$\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^5\right)\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^5$$ by this reasoning (or is it?).

I have no idea how to approach the second question. Is it valid to use the inclusion-exclusion principle there?

**Edit**: After a bit of searching, I found this in *Enumerative Combinatorics Volume 1*, exercise 44 in Chapter 4:

[image: Exercise 44 question]

and the solution:

[image: Exercise 44 answer]

Comment: You did question one for general $k$? Use it for question 2! The point is: You roll at least nine times, if you roll exactly nine times or exactly 10 times or ... (and these events are mutually exclusive!).

Comment: @martini: No, I didn't do question 1 for general $k$. I think there's something special about the fact that $11 = 2 \cdot 5 + 1$, which gives you the nice $Z$ in the middle of the 11-letter string (if that line of reasoning is even valid). If $k = 1000$ then I know that the last 5 letters must be 1s, but beyond that I'm lost (maybe tedious inclusion-exclusion?).

Comment: You're right ... seems like it's inclusion-exclusion ...

Comment: You might find some usefull information in this question:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112726/coin-tossed-until-two-consecutive-heads-or-tails-appear

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien: Thanks. I think this case is a bit more complicated though, because you cannot simply force the string to alternate between two symbols :(

Comment: Anything but a $5$ is a fail, so you can really see this has Heads or tails with probability of heads$=1/6$ say.

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien: Hmm... I was referring to the fact that we need 5, not just 2, consecutive appearances. I don't know how to set up a "history" of 5 symbols to deal with this.

Comment: @wj32 you are right it is not exactly this, but perhaps you can adapt some of the ideas, perhaps not.