# Law of total probability: Tossing a fair coin until two consecutive heads appears

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Question:

> A fair coin is tossed repeatedly until the sequence $HH$ of two consecutive heads appears, and the total number of tosses $n$ is recorded. Find $\Pr \left( {\left\{ {n = 2018} \right\}} \right)$? Hint given: Note that $n$ does not have a geometric/negative binomial distribution. Use the Law of Total Probability and condition on the outcome of the first two tosses and use the mutually exclusive and exhaustive events $\{HH\}$, $\{HT\}$, and $\{TH,TT\}$.

I know a similar question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/112726/422194), but this question asks to apply the law of total probability. Hopefully I'm not wrong in thinking this would have a different approach.

If we suppose the first two tosses is $HH$. Then how do we apply the law of total probability to find $\Pr \left( n \right)$? Would it look like:
$$\Pr \left( n \right) = \Pr \left( {n \mid HH} \right)\Pr \left( {HH} \right) + \Pr \left( {n \mid HT} \right)\Pr \left( {HT} \right) + \Pr \left( {n \mid TH} \right)\Pr \left( {TH} \right) + \Pr \left( {n \mid TT} \right)\Pr \left( {TT} \right)$$

If so, how does one find $\Pr \left( {n \mid HH} \right)$, $\Pr \left( {n \mid HT} \right)$, etc.?

Comment: Well, I suppose the intent is to work recursively.  Get an expression for $p_n$ in terms of $p_{n-1}, p_{n-2}$.

Comment: @lulu: What would $p_n$ represent?

Comment: The probability that the first $HH$ is completed on trial $n$.  Thus, the answer to your problem is $p_{2018}$.

Comment: @lulu: I'm still quite lost as to how to start off. How do I get the expression for $p_n$ in terms of $p_{n-1}$ and $p_{n-2}$?

Comment: There are exactly two paths to victory in $n$ trials (for $n>2$):  either you throw $T$ first and then achieve $HH$ in exactly $n-1$ trials, or you throw $HT$ first and then achieve $HH$ in exactly $n-2$ trials.

Comment: @lulu: How does the law of total probability come into play then?

Comment: Well, the total probability is, of course, the sum of the probabilities along those two paths.